# Three.js can't load DAE models

Tags: javascript, model, load, three.js, webgl

I have serious problems with not being able to load a model into Three.js.
First of all. I've downloaded https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/ and extracted it into a local WebMatrix server. Most examples run fine, exept for the ones I need the most.

webgl_loader_collada.html gives me

```
GET http://localhost:26238/three.js-master/examples/models/collada/monster/monster.dae 404 (Not Found)
```

webgl_loader_obj.html gives me

```
GET http://localhost:26238/three.js-master/examples/obj/male02/male02.obj 404 (Not Found)
```

I also have the ColladaLoader.js in the same folder.

When I try to load a Collada file like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
                loader.load("monster.dae", function loadCollada(collada) {
                                            var model = collada.scene;
                                            model.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
                                            model.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
                                            model.updateMatrix();
                                            scene.add(model);
                                            });
```

I get this:

```
GET http://localhost:26238/monster.dae 404 (Not Found)
ColladaLoader.js:108 load ColladaLoader.js:108

init webgl.html:43

onload webgl.html:107
```

I can get the JSON loader to load models though, but I need to have other formats working.

I'm stuck. I need this to work, but I have no clue what the problem is. I've copied code from working examples but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What does it do when you navigate to the URL by hand?

Comment: Haven't tried that before, when I did I could access all the files except the .dae files...? HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

Comment: Simply: you don't have the file then?

Comment: Seems like it's a WebMatrix problem then? It doens't seem to support dae files. So maybe I'll have to find another way of hosting it locally. Until then, is there any work arounds like putting it inside a string?

Comment: python -m SimpleHTTPServer http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using visual studio express... if so, you are probably using IIS express... to solve the issue I did this:

1. Go to X:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Documents\IISExpress\config
2. Edit the applicationhost.config
3. within the    `<staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">`    section add the following: `<mimeMap fileExtension=".dae" mimeType="text/xml" />`

I hope that helps!

Comment: For me it stopped throwing error however the model didn't show up.